# Android Universal Image Loader and GridView "Out of memory" on second launch

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter, universal-image-loader, picker

I have checked all the related posts so far, but did not managed to fix this "Out of memory on a 1843216-byte allocation" error my GridView activity generates.

Basically this activity displays the images from the phone's gallery in a GridView (as a multiple image picker), at first it loads everything just fine, at the second try I get the memory error and the GridView skips loading some of the image thumbnails.

I have disabled the memory caching by: ".cacheInMemory(false)", and using only disk caching with fixed ImageView width and height, but still got the memory error.

Could someone help me out? Thanks!

The CustomGalleryActivity, showing all pictures on the phone:

```
public class CustomGalleryActivity extends Activity {

    GridView gridGallery;
    Handler handler;
    GalleryAdapter adapter;

    ImageView imgNoMedia;
    Button btnGalleryOk;

    String action;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

        action = getIntent().getAction();
        if (action == null) {
            finish();
        }

        initImageLoader();
        init();
    }

    private void initImageLoader() {
        try {
            String CACHE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/.temp_tmp";
            new File(CACHE_DIR).mkdirs();

            File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(getBaseContext(),
                    CACHE_DIR);

            DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()                      
                    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                    .cacheInMemory(false)
                    .cacheOnDisk(true)
                    .considerExifParams(true)                   
                    .build();

            ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getBaseContext())           
                    .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)                       
                    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                    .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))                    
                    .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO);                
                    //.memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache());                  

            L.writeLogs(false); 
            ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
            imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();            
            imageLoader.destroy();
            imageLoader.init(config);


        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    private void init() {

        handler = new Handler();
        gridGallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridGallery);
        gridGallery.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        adapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), imageLoader);
        PauseOnScrollListener listener = new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader,
                true, true);
        gridGallery.setOnScrollListener(listener);

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Action.ACTION_MULTIPLE_PICK)) {

            findViewById(R.id.llBottomContainer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            gridGallery.setOnItemClickListener(mItemMulClickListener);
            adapter.setMultiplePick(true);

        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Action.ACTION_PICK)) {

            findViewById(R.id.llBottomContainer).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            gridGallery.setOnItemClickListener(mItemSingleClickListener);
            adapter.setMultiplePick(false);

        }

        gridGallery.setAdapter(adapter);
        imgNoMedia = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgNoMedia);

        btnGalleryOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGalleryOk);
        btnGalleryOk.setOnClickListener(mOkClickListener);

        new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.addAll(getGalleryPhotos());
                        checkImageStatus();
                    }
                });
                Looper.loop();
            };

        }.start();

    }

    private void checkImageStatus() {
        if (adapter.isEmpty()) {
            imgNoMedia.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            imgNoMedia.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    View.OnClickListener mOkClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<CustomGallery> selected = adapter.getSelected();

            String[] allPath = new String[selected.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < allPath.length; i++) {
                allPath[i] = selected.get(i).sdcardPath;
            }

            Intent data = new Intent().putExtra("all_path", allPath);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

            finish();

        }
    };
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemMulClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
            //adapter.changeSelection(v, position);
            if (adapter.getSelected().size() >= 15) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Max. 15 de poze pot fi selectate o data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                adapter.changeSelection(v, position);
            }

        }
    };

    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mItemSingleClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
            CustomGallery item = adapter.getItem(position);
            Intent data = new Intent().putExtra("single_path", item.sdcardPath);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
        }
    };

    private ArrayList<CustomGallery> getGalleryPhotos() {
        ArrayList<CustomGallery> galleryList = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();

        try {
            final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
            final String orderBy = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor imagecursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,
                    null, null, orderBy);

            if (imagecursor != null && imagecursor.getCount() > 0) {

                while (imagecursor.moveToNext()) {
                    CustomGallery item = new CustomGallery();

                    int dataColumnIndex = imagecursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

                    item.sdcardPath = imagecursor.getString(dataColumnIndex);

                    galleryList.add(item);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // show newest photo at beginning of the list
        Collections.reverse(galleryList);
        return galleryList;
    }

}
```

And its CustomAdapter:

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater infalter;
    private ArrayList<CustomGallery> data = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    private boolean isActionMultiplePick;

    public GalleryAdapter(Context c, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        infalter = (LayoutInflater) c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mContext = c;
        this.imageLoader = imageLoader;
        // clearCache();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CustomGallery getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void setMultiplePick(boolean isMultiplePick) {
        this.isActionMultiplePick = isMultiplePick;
    }

    public void selectAll(boolean selection) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            data.get(i).isSeleted = selection;

        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public boolean isAllSelected() {
        boolean isAllSelected = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if (!data.get(i).isSeleted) {
                isAllSelected = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        return isAllSelected;
    }

    public boolean isAnySelected() {
        boolean isAnySelected = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if (data.get(i).isSeleted) {
                isAnySelected = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return isAnySelected;
    }

    public ArrayList<CustomGallery> getSelected() {
        ArrayList<CustomGallery> dataT = new ArrayList<CustomGallery>();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if (data.get(i).isSeleted) {
                dataT.add(data.get(i));
            }
        }

        return dataT;
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<CustomGallery> files) {

        try {
            this.data.clear();
            this.data.addAll(files);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void changeSelection(View v, int position) {

        if (data.get(position).isSeleted) {
            data.get(position).isSeleted = false;
        } else {
            data.get(position).isSeleted = true;
        }

        ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).imgQueueMultiSelected.setSelected(data
                .get(position).isSeleted);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = infalter.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imgQueue = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgQueue);

            holder.imgQueueMultiSelected = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgQueueMultiSelected);

            if (isActionMultiplePick) {
                holder.imgQueueMultiSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.imgQueueMultiSelected.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.imgQueue.setTag(position);

        try {

            imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + data.get(position).sdcardPath,
                    holder.imgQueue, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                            holder.imgQueue.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_media);
                            super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
                        }
                    });

            if (isActionMultiplePick) {

                holder.imgQueueMultiSelected
                        .setSelected(data.get(position).isSeleted);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgQueue;
        ImageView imgQueueMultiSelected;
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        imageLoader.clearDiscCache();
        imageLoader.clearMemoryCache();
    }

    public void clear() {
        data.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this with Picasso library instead of using image loader library. Hope this may helpful for you.

https://github.com/square/picasso